# Rungithub() - shiny app that contains ui.R and server.R in the same R file

Tags: r, github, shiny

I know that if the application will contain 2 separate files: ui.R and server.R, I could run:

```
library(shiny)    
shiny::runGitHub('username/repo_name')
```

Now, is it possible to run a shiny application hosted in Github which contains the ui and server in only one R file? For example:

```
library(shiny)    
shiny::runGitHub('manolo20/shinytreemap')
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error message you get from `shiny::runGitHub('manolo20/shinytreemap')`

> Error in shinyAppDir(x) : App dir must contain either app.R or server.R.

the anser is yes. you just need to use the name `app.R` for the R file containing the app. Also, this file must be at the top level of the repository unless you use the `subdir` argument.

Comment: Thank you, one last thing how should I refer to my dataset within the `app.R`. Currently I have it as: `weights <- readRDS("/data/treemap1.rds")` but I am getting and error message that says: `Warning in gzfile(file, "rb") :
  cannot open compressed file '/data/treemap1.rds', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection`

Comment: is your datafile in the version control? Try putting it in the same foler as the app.

Comment: I uploaded the weights.rds to the same folder as the app.R and I referred it as  `readRDS("treemap1.rds")` and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I think the problem with your first path was the leading slash, so this should work as well if your data is in a subfolder: `readRDS("data/treemap1.rds")`

Comment: You are absolutely right. My mistake was indeed the `/` at the beginning. Thanks a lot, Gregor.